# strange bug using the three dot "..." argument

Tags: r, ellipsis

I need help figuring out what is going on here.

```
g <- function(x, y=NULL, z=NULL) invisible(NULL)

h <- function(...) {
    args <- as.list(match.call(g))[-1]
    print(args)
    ## lapply(args, eval)
}

f <- function(...) {
    h(...)
}
```

Function `h()` prints a named list of unevaluated arguments and then tries
to evaluate the arguments.

See what happens when `f` is called with `z=3` and `z=-3`.

```
> f(1, z=3)
$x
[1] 1

$z
[1] 3

> f(1, z=-3)
$x
[1] 1

$z
..2
```

What is this `..2`?  Notice that `h(1, z=-3)` produces a different output:

```
> h(1, z=-3)
$x
[1] 1

$z
-3
```

Comment: It's a bit harsh to call this a bug when it's really just a part of the R Language definition you might not understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second question is easy. You have a function that creates a side-effect of printing from the inside of a function as the last called function. The `print` function returns its argument as a value so when the function exits the read-eval-print behavior of the console displays it again.

The first question delves into the inner workings a bit more. The items in the ellipsis get temporary names: `..1`, `..2`, `..3`, etc. When using the minus sign in front of the `2` you are actually applying a unary operator to change its value. You get exactly the same result with `log(2)` as the second argument:

```
> f(1,log(2))
$x
[1] 1

$y
..2
```

I think the reason that the `..2` doesn't appear when the second argument to f is atomic is that a different evaluation process (or no evaluation) process is needed. The same behavior occurs with a character object.

```
> f(1,"a")
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] "a"
```

Comment: I removed the 2nd question as it was a mistake on my part (I had temporarily uncommented the `lapply` line).